# How to communicate with parted interpreter via python?

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

```
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE,STDOUT

a=Popen('parted -s',stdout = PIPE, stderr = STDOUT, shell = True)
a.communicate(input="print".encode())
string=a.stdout.read()
```

I want to use the "print" command within parted, how do I do so?

Comment: Note that `a.stdout.read()` will block until it reaches an `EOF` and thus will block until parted exits. If this is the desired functionality, it would simply be much easier and safer to call `stdoutdata, stderrdata  = a.communicate("print")`. After parted returns, all that was printed to stdout and stderr will be in stdoutdata and stderrdata respectively. if you go with this route, you also don't need `stdout = PIPE` or `stderr = PIPE`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this without sending input to the child's stdin, just use the command line and execute it with [`subprocess.check_output()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output):

```
import shlex
import subprocess

DEVICE = '/dev/sda'
cmd = 'parted -s {} print'.format(DEVICE)

output = subprocess.check_output(shlex.split(cmd))

>>> print output
Model: ATA Hitachi HTS54756 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 640GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   Type      File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  210MB  209MB  primary   ntfs         boot
 2      210MB   322GB  322GB  primary   ntfs
 4      322GB   640GB  318GB  extended
 5      322GB   322GB  524MB  logical   ext4
 6      322GB   640GB  318GB  logical                lvm
 3      640GB   640GB  108MB  primary   fat32        lba
```